# how can i find longest word from a given string in php?

Tags: php, database, string, graph

I want to create a graph from the data fetching from database. I don't have much knowledge of Json or xml..Is it possible to draw Graph without using them.. I searched on net and found about Google Graph but there are no tutorials on how to use them. I also tried to find out books on this topic but unable to find any.

Kindly tell me any good and easy Api to draw graph from MySQL data, and any video tutorials that can help me to learn

Comment: Try to split you question in two... heading is asking something different than text. Calculating word length is first step, visualizing data second. Also please post your current php code, so someone can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code john...

> $lon) {
>         $lon = strlen($word);
>         $lonWord = $word;    } }
>   
>   echo $lonWord; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` your string and by using `strlen` you can do this

```
<?php
$string = "Your STRING";
$words  = explode(' ', $string);

$longestWordLength = 0;
$longestWord = '';

foreach ($words as $word) {
   if (strlen($word) > $longestWordLength) {
      $longestWordLength = strlen($word);
      $longestWord = $word;
   }
}

echo $longestWord;
?>
```